# How can I get a travel visa to Bhutan?

Tags: bhutan

I always have been passionate about the beautiful country Bhutan, but after searching for some infomation, I found out that Bhutan restricts the travellers there. So how can I gain a visa to this country? What is the requirement to get a Bhutan visa and where do have it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All visitors to Bhutan other than those from India, Bangladesh and the Maldives require a visa. Visas are processed by licensed Bhutan tour operators and issued only to visitors on all-inclusive prepaid tours. The formalities are done in Bhutan, for which you will need to provide a copy of the photo page in your passport. A visa clearance letter will be issued once the payment for your tour (including a US$40 visa fee) is received and a visa is stamped into your passport on arrival.

The Tourism Council of Bhutan web site has details of the visa process [here](http://www.tourism.gov.bt/plan/visa).

There is a directory of licensed tour operators on the same site [here](http://www.tourism.gov.bt/directory/tour-operator). You can deal direct or through an overseas travel agent.

Comment: You're talking specifically about tourist visas, or all visas?

Comment: @gerrit Good point. This is all taken from the Bhutan tourism web site, so it's tourist visas, which covers the OP's question. The Bhutan government web site is variously down for maintenance, or populated with broken links so it's a bit difficult to find information for other visas.